# Error - Spark Scala streaming -checkpoint Location must be specified

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, spark-structured-streaming

When I am trying to run the Scala code from IntelliJ IDEA.

**Aim:** stream data from Kafka to HDFS.

**Getting error**

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: checkpointLocation must be specified either through option("checkpointLocation", ...) or SparkSession.conf.set("spark.sql.streaming.checkpointLocation", ...);
    at org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.StreamingQueryManager$$anonfun$3.apply(StreamingQueryManager.scala:210)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.StreamingQueryManager$$anonfun$3.apply(StreamingQueryManager.scala:205)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.StreamingQueryManager.createQuery(StreamingQueryManager.scala:204)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.StreamingQueryManager.startQuery(StreamingQueryManager.scala:278)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.DataStreamWriter.start(DataStreamWriter.scala:282)
    at kafka_stream.kafka_stream$.read_from_kafka(kafka_stream.scala:67)
    at kafka_stream.kafka_stream$.main(kafka_stream.scala:24)
    at kafka_stream.kafka_stream.main(kafka_stream.scala)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

**We tried**

Added this code after writing to the console.

it is looking for checkpoint dir whenever I try to write the data in HDFS.

```
val query = values //.orderBy("window")
      .repartition(1)
      .writeStream
      .outputMode("append")
      .format("parquet")
      .option("checkpointLaocation","checkpoints")
      .option("path", "hdfs://hostname:8020/tmp/")
      //.option("path", "data")
     .start()
     .awaitTermination()
```

Any help on it appreciated?

Comment: `checkpointLocation` not `checkpointLaocation`.

Comment: Sorry for my bed.  Also,  do we need to mention port 8020 as well or just by passing FQDN will  work

Comment: Just passing FQDN should be fine.